# Video editing plugin for Audacity or stand alone program

Tags: video-editing, audio-editing

I have been looking a while for some sort of video editing plugin for Audacity that would basically just let me edit the audio track of the video without having to separate the audio from the container and work with the audio track then recombine them.

I would be fine with any other program that would help too.

I am looking for a program with good audio editing functionality that can work on the audio track of a video file.

Bonus if the program would let me delete a section from the audio track and the video track at the same time or at least without having to carefully mark the timestamp I am starting and stopping the cut at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the less often mentioned facilities in the [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) 3D Modelling, Animation and Rendering toolkit is the [Video Editor](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/sequencer/index.html) which also has an [Audio Track Editor](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/sequencer/audio.html).

While it is not as powerful a sound editor as Audacity it does allow you to do the mixing, volume control on each track, adding sounds from .WAV or .MP3 files as well as from Movies, have volume curves, animated cross fades, etc.

It also allows drop, (or rearrange),  sections of the audio and video together, *bonus point*.

Better yet:

- Price: Free and open source
- Platform: Mac OS-X, Windows 7/8, GNU/Linux *or build it yourself from source for other platforms potentially*.
- Multiple Video formats supported.
- Add title sequences, etc. which can be animated.
- Built in transition effects + plug-in effects.
- Potentially add in special effects - see [Project London](http://projectlondonmovie.com/) for a full length movie produced primarily with Blender, *the special effects are mind blowing*.

*Disclaimer: My only associations with Blender is as a user and supporter, with Project London was as a crowd funding supporter.*

Comment: I will look into this.  My primary use case for this question is taking videos that already exist and normalizing the sound tracks so that the dialog is not 10% the volume of the action scenes.

Comment: You should find that simple to do with blender.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to figure out the same thing. I have heard that the free program Audacity allows this, but I've not been able to get it to run on my computer so I cannot personally attest to it. I can, however second that Blender does. I use Blender all the time for things like this and love it, but it does have a learning curve and frustrates a lot of people before they figure it out since it behaves differently than other programs you may be familiar with. Also, it's audio abilities are limited to things like volume, pitch and balance, but it does allow you to attach a sound to a 3d object and move it around in 3d space and have realistic doppler which is cool. I have a Facebook group called Blender Ask and Answer if you want some help in the program.

Comment: Some links and white space would make your answer better quality. Can you [edit] it?